# Maven: How to create assembly with snapshot artifacts without timestamps file name?

Tags: maven-2, assemblies, versioning, maven-3, artifacts

I've a repository containing snapshot artifacts with timestamps.

I want to create an assembly, that contains the dependencies. This works fine. But the artifact names contains the timestamp. So i wonder how to remove the timestamp from filename for the assembly only.

I've used this *dependencySet*:

```
<outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.version}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
```

But version seams to contain already the timestamp. So is there any chance to get a *1.1.1-SNAPSHOT* instead of *1.1.1-20100323.071348-182*?

I'm using version 2.2-beta-4 of maven-assembly-plugin.

Comment: What versions of maven and of the assembly plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.2-beta-4 of maven-assembly-plugin. (I've added this information to my question)

Comment: The accepted answer works perfectly well with Maven 3 and version 2.2.1 of the assembly plugin.

Comment: I also have same requirement, can you please share which file I need to add this tag into? This file is added apart from pom.xml?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Could you try the following for the `outputFileNameMapping`:

```
${artifactId}-${baseVersion}.${extension}
```

According to issues like [MASSEMBLY-67](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-67), [MASSEMBLY-91](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-91):

> Using `${baseVersion}` for cases where you want to preserve the -SNAPSHOT naming, the plugin retains the ability to use `${version}` for the timestamp-buildnumber naming, which is useful for describing the exact library version included in the assembly.

**Update:** After feedback from the OP, the exact syntax is (wasn't totally sure of this):

```
${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.baseVersion}.${artifact.extension}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a little change and it works fine:  

       <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.baseVersion}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>

Comment: @marabol You're welcome. Glad it works. I wasn't totally sure for the syntax of properties but I thought you would figure it out :)

Comment: You may also add the classifier: ${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.baseVersion}${dashClassifier?}.${artifact.extension}

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue when trying to build a bundle with the assembly plugin which contained a folder with the version number (I'm packaging WSDLs and XSDs).

The workaround I found is quite simple, I put the actual version number in a property (e.g. 1.0), which makes it available in the bundle.xml file for the assembly plugin, and set the pom version's to:

```
<version>${service.version}-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

This way the content of my package isn't influenced by the SNAPSHOT marker, in particular it isn't modified when doing the release.